# Radio button works in fiddle, but not on page

Tags: jquery-mobile, radio-button

I want to put a jquery mobile radio button in a document. [This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/steveo_88/g8o0L1uf/) is a small-scale representation of what I want. It works as I want.

But when I make `file.php`, with html/javascript that are identical to the code in the html and js windows in the fiddle, and load that file into my browser, the js behaviour is not there. i.e., when I click on either "senior" or "student" nothing happens.

The "external resources" in the fiddle came directly as copy/paste from the jquery and jquery mobile links in the  in file.php.

Anybody have an idea why code that works in fiddle doesn't work in a page loaded to the browser?

Here in its entirety is file.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'> 
    <title>Electricity in Ontario</title> 
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='HourDay_Table.css' >
  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js'></script>

</head> 

<body> 

<div data-role='page' data-add-back-btn='true' class='ui-alt-icon'>

<script>
//tabs and the hide/show column function


$('#myForm input').on('change', function () {
    var pog = {train_cost:"900",plane_cost:"777"};
    var lca = {train_cost:"5000",plane_cost:"8000"};
    var active = $('input[type="radio"]:checked', '#myForm').val();
    if (active =="sen") {
        $('#tab1 .view-train').text(pog.train_cost);
        $('#tab1 .view-plane').text( pog.plane_cost);
    } else if (active =="stu") {
        $('#tab1 .view-train').text(lca.train_cost);
        $('#tab1 .view-plane').text(lca.plane_cost);
    } else {
        alert('you selected nothing');
    }
});
</script>

   <form id='myForm'>
    <fieldset data-role='controlgroup' data-type='horizontal'>
        <label for='senior'>Senior</label>
        <input type='radio' name='switch' id='senior' value='sen' checked='checked'>
        <input type='radio' name='switch' id='student' value='stu'>
        <label for='student'>Student</label>
    </fieldset>
</form>
<table id="tab1">
    <tr>
        <th>Mode</th>
        <th>Miles</th>
        <th>Cost</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Train</td>
        <td>3.9</td>
        <td class="view-train"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Plane</td>
        <td>1000</td>
        <td class="view-plane"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script is set before the `<form>` is added to the DOM, and so the script tries to bind the listener to `#myForm input` before it exists. Simply wrap it in:

```
$(function() {/*your code here*/});
```

Now this code will only execute after the entire page is loaded.

It should look like this:

```
$(function() {
$('#myForm input').on('change', function () {
alert('x');
var pog = {train_cost:"900",plane_cost:"777"};
var lca = {train_cost:"5000",plane_cost:"8000"};
var active = $('input[type="radio"]:checked', '#myForm').val();
if (active =="sen") {
    $('#tab1 .view-train').text(pog.train_cost);
    $('#tab1 .view-plane').text( pog.plane_cost);
} else if (active =="stu") {
    $('#tab1 .view-train').text(lca.train_cost);
    $('#tab1 .view-plane').text(lca.plane_cost);
} else {
    alert('you selected nothing');
}
});
});
```

Edit: to explain `$(function() {});` is short for `$(document).ready(function() {});`. All of your jQuery code that interacts with DOM should always be enclosed in this to ensure everything is loaded before you try to change it. To clean it up you can wrap your code in a function like this:

```
function myFunction()
{
    //your code
}
```

and then call it like this:

```
$(myFunction);
```

(there are no parentheses, because you pass myFunction as an argument to another function, not call it directly)

Comment: yes, that works. Many thanks. I tried following the action in Chrome Developer Tools, and got pretty deep into some totally incomprehensible stuff. Your explanation is much appreciated -- helps me learn this.

Comment: should have mentioned: prior to your reply I had tried moving the js into the <head> which I figured might have the same effect as $(document).ready(function(){}, but no dice.